# Equivalent of "false alarm" in a positive context

Tags: expressions, antonyms

Is there an equivalent for "false alarm" in a positive context?

For example imagine everybody is waiting for a miracle to happen, after a while someone says "hey! the miracle happened" and then everybody finds out it wasn't true.

**EDIT:**

From Oxford dictionary:

[Alarm](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/alarm?region=uk&q=alarm): an anxious awareness of danger.

So false alarm is linked to announcement of a danger, that turned out to be false. I'm looking for an equivalent, if there is any, for mistakenly announcing something hopeful and positive.

Comment: How about "false positive"?

Comment: "False positive" can mean a lot of things...

Comment: The equivalent is "false alarm". As a metaphor it refers to an announcement which is afterwards discovered to be false, whether that announcement was positive or negative.

Comment: @aligf: So can a lot of things.

Comment: @MετάEd From Oxford dictionary "Alarm: an anxious awareness of danger". So false alarm is linked to announcement of a danger that was false. I'm looking for an equivalent, if there is any, for announcement of something positive.

Comment: False hope / wishful thinking?

Comment: I agree with MetaEd.  *False alarm* can be used for at least one thing positive. For example, an expecting mother rushes to the hospital because of contractions, but they fail to continue to the expected end.  When she comes back without having given birth, she could say it was a *false alarm*.

Comment: @SpareOom I have defended my claim and turned it into an answer.

Comment: As @MετάEd says, "false alarm" is a completely appropriate idiom to use in this case, despite what the word "alarm" means in isolation.  Are you hoping to find some expression that intrinsically communicates a positive result for poetic reasons (i.e. you are not satisfied that "false alarm" could be either positive or negative)?

Comment: The "positive" in "false positive" does not necessarily mean "good", but "affirmitive". It is often a very bad thing. Like if you have positive results of a test for hepatitis, you would be very happy if it turned out to be a false positive.

Comment: @aspsillers Yes, I was hoping to get an expression that is intrinsically positive, and for example can only be used for positive and hopeful news. My initial gut feeling that there is such an expression turns out to be a false alarm.

Comment: I think `alarm` being negative is begging the question a little. Technically, my `alarm` clock is not warning me of impending doom or danger, and Googling `"false alarm" "surprise party"` brings up real world usage of `false alarm` in a positive context as I understand it from the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The equivalent is *false alarm*:

> *“The doctors came flying in the room, a whole team of doctors, and said, ‘You’re not going to believe this. We have a liver for you. You’re getting a liver transplant in just a few hours,’” she said. Unfortunately, it was a **false alarm**. The doctors said it was difficult to find the perfect liver for Shiroda, who is blood type A-positive.* —“Family gives special thanks to organ donation”, *WAFB*.
>
> [*T*]*he Princeton Dental Resource Center said research showed chocolate could fight cavity-causing plaque* … [*u*]*nfortunately, it was a **false alarm**, one that demonstrates the pitfalls of getting advice on dental health from a candy manufacturer*. —“Find Who’s Behind Dubious Declarations”, *SunSentinel*.
>
> *@RealMichelleT tweeting about Mud Wrestling and got all excited. Unfortunately, it was a **false alarm**.* —James D (@TuckingFypos) on Twitter

As an idiomatic expression, *false alarm* refers to a signal which is afterwards discovered to be false: originally a literal false alarm (such as a fire alarm which sounds in the absence of fire, or a false report of fire to the city), but now also a metaphor in which the signal is not a literal alarm and not necessarily even an alarming (scary) thing.

The examples above were found by googling [ `"unfortunately it was a false alarm"` ]. A *Wordnik* search for *false-alarm* returns additional metaphorical examples of “alarms”, some with no negative association, such as:

> *Gould is referring, of course, to the whipped-up brouhaha surrounding his own three **false-alarm** “revolutions” in Darwinism: exaptation, punctuated equilibrium, and, most recently, species selectionism.*

In the example above, the false alarm is positive: revolutions in the scientific understanding of how species evolve.

For an idiomatic expression such as *false alarm*, it can be misleading to look up the individual words instead of the expression. Consider instead the attestations given in the following dictionaries:

> A *signal* or warning that is groundless —“false alarm”, sense 2 in *American Heritage Dictionary of the English Language, Fourth Edition* [*sense 2*]
>
> [S]omething that excites unfounded alarm *or expectation* —“false alarm”, sense 2 at *Dictionary.com*

Comment: Sometime “false alarm” is in quotes because, as you said,  many of these alarms are not really true at all, but people accept false alarms only when the facts don't match what they believe.

Comment: "false alarm" is not really the best choice for the the OP's use, though certainly technically correct.

Comment: Best I can tell, @Carlo_R., you are saying *false alarm* refers only to situations where a person ignores facts in favor of their beliefs. I do not think that is so.

Comment: @Carlo_R. Not sure what you mean. By definition, a "false alarm" is "not really true at all". If it turned out to be true, it wouldn't be a false alarm, but an actual, true, alarm.

Comment: I absolutely agree with everything you say here ... but it may still not be suitable for the OPs purposes, if what he needs is a term that clearly indicates that the news seemed good until it turned out to be in error. 'Not saying I have a better alternative. :-)

Comment: @Jay Yes, that is the problem with word and phrase requests. There is very often no possibility of a verifiably correct answer, because whatever the OP "likes" is the correct answer, and that is a pure matter of opinion. That is why such questions are really off topic "Not Constructive". Or, in many cases, "General Reference".

Answer (score 4):

"Dashed hopes" or "having one's bubble burst" fits the scenario.

Answer (score 3):

"False dawn" or "anticlimax" would work in certain scenarios.

Comment: +1 false dawn, great alternative. Please also cite a reputable source.

Comment: +1 for anticlimax as well :)

Answer (score 3):

Consider *[disillusionment](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/disillusionment)*, “A feeling of disappointment, akin to depression, arising from the realization that something is not what it was expected or believed to be...”.

Actually, disillusioned is how people feel after a  “positive false alarm”, and *disillusionment* may refer to such disappointment or to the unveiling of the truth.  For the false alarm event itself, consider   *[mirage](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mirage)*:   “An optical phenomenon [...] giving the appearance of there being refuge in the distance” or “(figuratively) An illusion.”

Comment: Disillusionment doesn't have the feel of a sudden let down, but that could just be me.

Comment: Depends on just what the original poster is looking for, but I don't think "disillusionment" fits. That it the feeling that one has after good news turns out to be false, not the news itself. The corresponding term for bad news that turns out to be false would be "relief", not "false alarm".

Answer (score 1):

*Disappointment*.

"Cathy had been in the hospital, and the doctors did not think she had long to live, so we agreed to a radical treatment. I suppose we let ourselves become too hopeful, because it turned out to be a disappointment. The funeral is on Wednesday."

Comment: Your story is not an example of a false alarm.